# ETL из Postgres в ClickHouse быстро

Tags: postgresql, clickhouse, etl

Есть OLTP БД на Postgres, необходимо получить результаты запросов из этой БД в ClickHouse. Т.е. создать некое упрощенное подобие DWH, где будут храниться просто "вьюхи" для дальнейшей их визуализации в BI инструменте.

Postgres и ClickHouse располагаются на двух разных машинах.
Как максимально быстро (или хотя бы правильно) осуществить данную операцию?

Пока, по незнанию, делаю так:

1. Считываю результат запроса в Pandas с помощью read_sql.
2. Что-то еще делаю с этим датафреймом или не делаю, опционально.
3. Разбиваю датафрейм построчно на список кортежей и гружу из в ClickHouse через insert пачками по 50-100к записей.

Сам питон в свою очередь используется на моем ПК, т.е. я сначала скачиваю из Postgres все себе на ПК, затем с ПК в ClickHouse. Получается не очень быстро, чувствую, есть какой-то другой подход.

Есть похожая тема, но тут говорится о том, как конкретную таблицу перенести из одной БД в другую.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73377036/how-to-etl-my-postgresql-data-into-a-clickhouse-datawarehouse

Может мой подход в корне неверный и надо все таблицы переносить в ClickHouse, на основе которых я выполняю запрос?

Comment: https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/integrations/postgresql

Comment: Да, эту штуку читал, как раз про нее и писал, что она позволяется приконектиться из ClickHouse к таблице в Postgres. А что если мне надо получить результат джойна нескольких таблиц? Или мне нужно подключиться к каждой из таблиц отдельно из Clickhouse и затем просто писать запрос к подключенным таблицам, как-будто бы они уже у меня в Clickhouse?

Comment: join можно сохранить как view.

Comment: А сами таблицы мне обязательно в ClickHouse для этого "качать"? Пока не совсем понятно, допустим, мне нужен результат джойна десяти таблиц. Мне нужно все 10 таблиц перетянуть в кликхаус и 11-ая будет вью этих таблиц. Или мне достаточно как-то подключиться к этим десяти таблицам и в результате у меня будет только лишь вью в кликхаус?

Comment: Конечно нет. Вью нужно сделать в постгресе. Из кликхауса обращайтесь ко вью как к одной таблице.

Comment: В том то и дело, что в постргесе я ничего сделать не могу, у меня там реплика и добавлять вью или как-то что-то видоизменять нельзя. В таком случае как быть?

Comment: Добавил в ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В кликхаус есть драйвер подключения к постгресу

https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/integrations/postgresql

Используйте вариант MaterializedPostgreSQL для копирования данных или PostgreSQL для пересылки запросов.

```
CREATE DATABASE db1_postgres
ENGINE = MaterializedPostgreSQL('postgres-host.domain.com:5432', 'db1', 'clickhouse_user', 'ClickHouse_123')
SETTINGS materialized_postgresql_tables_list = 'table1';
```

Будет постоянно копировать изменения table1 в clickhouse. Можно указать список таблиц. Таблицы в этом случае соединяют в join на стороне clickhouse.

Можно собрать join в view на стороне postgres. Тогда подключаетесь ко view через PostgreSQL.

```
CREATE TABLE db_in_ch.table1
(
    id UInt64,
    column1 String
)
ENGINE = PostgreSQL('postgres-host.domain.com:5432', 'db_in_psg', 'table1', 'clickhouse_user', 'ClickHouse_123');
```

Где table1 подготовленное view

Comment: Спасибо, остановился пока на варианте PostgreSQL, чтобы данные в кликхаус не качать, все работает как часы. По возможности, присоединяйтесь к следующему вопросу) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1545010